# windows batch to split string on first occurrence of a delimiter

Tags: batch-file

I have a parameter string read from a properties file. One of the properties is as below:

```
"CUSTOM_JAVA_OPTIONS=-Dhttp.proxyHost=webcache.example.com -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080"
```

I need to split this string on the first occurrence of "=" and set a parameter with the value:

```
-Dhttp.proxyHost=webcache.example.com -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080
```

I am trying to split the string first on the = token and then remove the fist sub-string token from the original string. 
In the below code %%G will be set to "CUSTOM_JAVA_OPTIONS" and I am trying to remove this from the original string "TESTSTR"

```
@echo off

set "TESTSTR=CUSTOM_JAVA_OPTIONS=-Dhttp.proxyHost=webcache.example.com 
-Dhttp.proxyPort=8080"

SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

FOR /F "tokens=1,2 delims==" %%G IN ("%TESTSTR%") DO (

  echo Name=%%G
  echo Value=%%H
  set removestr=%%G

  echo TESTSTR=!TESTSTR!
  echo removestr=!removestr!

  set "str=!TESTSTR:%removestr%=!"
  echo str=!str!
  )
pause
```

The above does not seem to work, it produces:

```
Name=CUSTOM_JAVA_OPTIONS
Value=-Dhttp.proxyHost
TESTSTR=CUSTOM_JAVA_OPTIONS=-Dhttp.proxyHost=webcache.example.com -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080
removestr=CUSTOM_JAVA_OPTIONS
str=TESTSTR:=
```

Expected result needs to be:

```
 str=-Dhttp.proxyHost=webcache.example.com -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This could be simplified to:

```
@echo off

set "TESTSTR=CUSTOM_JAVA_OPTIONS=-Dhttp.proxyHost=webcache.example.com -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080"

FOR /F "tokens=1* delims==" %%G IN ("%TESTSTR%") DO set "str=%%H"
echo TESTSTR=%TESTSTR%
echo.str=%str%
pause
```

There are 2 tokens:

```
1. Text up to 1st delimiter
2. Everything else after first delimiter (*)
```

Note that by echoing the variables outside of the FOR loop you don't need to enable delayed expansion.

Comment: This will most likely always meet the OP's needs. But your description is not quite correct. `for /f "tokens=1* delims=" %%G in ("A==B")` will yield `A` and `B`, when the correct result should be `A` and `=B`.

Answer (score 2):

Your code fails entirely because `%removestr%` is expanded when the command is initially parsed, and your entire loop (code block) is parsed all at once. So `%removestr%` expands to the value that existed before your loop was entered. In your case, the variable is undefined. So `!TESTSTR:%removestr%=!` becomes `!TESTSTR:=!`, which finally becomes `TESTSTR:=`.

You get closer if you use `%%G` directly, instead of assigning an environment variable.
`set str=!TESTSTR:%%G=!` yields `=-Dhttp.proxyHost=webcache.example.com -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080`

You can then use `set str=!str:~1!"` to remove the leading `=`.

`set str=!TESTSTR:%%G==!` will not work because the search strings stops at the first occurrence of `=`, so the result is `==-Dhttp.proxyHost=webcache.example.com -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080`

[The RGuggisberg answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56390096/1012053) is the most convenient method to get your desired result. (You may want both `%%G` and `%%H`).

However, it technically does not break at the first `=`. It actually breaks at the first string of contiguous `=` because FOR /F does not parse empty tokens.

So `for /f "tokens=1* delims==" %%G in ("A==B==C")` yields `A` for `%%G` (correct), and `B==C` (incorrect) for `%%H`. The correct value should be `=B==C`.

Answer (score 0):

If the first character after the **`=`** character is always a **`-`**, then the following method may also work for you:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "TESTSTR=CUSTOM_JAVA_OPTIONS=-Dhttp.proxyHost=webcache.example.com -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080"
Set "REST=-%TESTSTR:*-=%"
Set "FIRST=%TESTSTR:-="&:"%"
Set "FIRST=%FIRST:~,-1%"
Echo [%FIRST%] [%REST%] & Pause
```

*The bottom line is simply to show you the information.*